# Prepositions that can be used with the verb Admit (meaning allow (someone) to enter a place.)

Tags: prepositions

I'm trying to convey the following information in a formal sentence and I'm having a hard time because I don't know what prepositions I can use with the verb admit as in admitted to UBC, for example.

I'm trying to say that:

> I got into (name) High school in 2020. That year, 5000 students applied and took the entrance exam and only 8 percent were admitted."

Can you guys give me a sentance I can use?

Comment: What's wrong with 'to'?

Comment: The example sentence you present is perfectly correct English. What makes you think there's something wrong with it? _Admitted_ doesn't need a preposition.